# Space or no space? '3x bigger' vs. '3 x bigger'

Tags: numbers, symbols

Which one is a correct form in English?

- '3x bigger forest'

or

- '3 x bigger forest?

With a space after the number or without a space?

Comment: In a sentence (as opposed to a mathematical formula) we would use the word _times_.

Comment: As Kate says, you would write 'a three-times-bigger forest' (hyphenating a compound adjective because it is before the noun that it modifies), or 'a forest three times bigger'. Numbers smaller than (often) 11 are written as words.

Answer (score 3):

You should write out the words.

> The New Forest is twenty times bigger than the Ashdown Forest.

It is best not to use this as an attribute.

> *The New Forest is a three times bigger forest.

If writing mathematics, put spaces around the multiplication symbol (and please avoid using x for multiplication)  2 × 3 = 5.  (or in some places with a dot without spaces 2·3 = 5) It is much better to use an equation editor or TeX $2\times\3=5$ and let the software get the spacing right.

Comment: Amen, @jamesk, amen!  The multiplication sign is no more a letter x than the addition sign is a letter t.

Comment: @PaulTanenbaum Yes. the multiplication symbol **×** is smaller than a lower case letter **x** and the multiplication symbol is in the middle of the line vertically, whereas the letter x is on the line. You can type a multiplication sign on a Windows keyboard if it has a number pad by holding down the Alt key and typing 0215 on the keypad.

Comment: If nothing else the second example makes us ask the question "three times bigger than what?". If you;ve already mentioned a forest as a comparison then you should just write "The New Forest is three times bigger"

Answer (score 3):

It's 3x, without a space. As noted by others, there are usually better ways to write it in a sentence, but the shorthand has its uses, such as in technical specifications or various kinds of games. The spacing is overwhelmingly consistent in these settings.

Answer (score 1):

The multiplication sign × **is** suitable for use in running prose, but only in fairly technical material. And even there it is used not to specify additive differences in magnitude, but only multiplicative ones.

To illustrate what this means, I’d point out that your example, “three times bigger” is at best ambiguous. It can mean either “three times the size”—as, for instance, a thing thing that is 15 m tall compared to another that is 5 m tall—or, because it includes the comparative *big**ger***, “three times again the size”—so a further 15 m taller than the five-meter thing, and thus 20 m tall. The latter interpretation is consistent with the (only possible) meaning of “50 percent bigger.” And that’s what I mean by “additive difference in magnitude”: it has an additional 50% of the other thing’s size.

So a photograph of a bacterium made through a microscope would be described as showing the organism “at 2000× magnification” if its likeness of a feature that is actually 0.003 mm long measures in the final image as 6 mm long. Not 2000 times larger, but 2000 times the size. And what is meant when we speak of “a pair of 10× binoculars”? They create for, say, a tree that subtends an angle *a* in the visual field of one’s unaided eye an image subtending an angle 10*a*. Thus they make faraway objects appear as though they were only 1/10 their actual distance from the viewer.